# Unable to make RDP connection to AWS windows instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created windows 12 R2 Base EC2 instance with VPC in AWS. But I am unable to do RDP to that instance.
I have checked the following things :

```
1. Instance has elastic IP with IPv4 public Ip 
2 .Security group : Inbound: Type :RDS ,Protocol:TCP, Port range: 3389 , Source :0.0.0.0/0 .Outbound : All traffic, destination:0.0.0.0/0. 
3. Route Table : Destination 0.0.0.0/0 Target **************** Status Active Propagated No
```

But still I am not able do RDS connection. Any suggestions would be very much helpful to me.

Answer (score 5):

Are the EC2 instances in a public subnet? You can check to see this in the route table of your subnet - you must have an Internet Gateway configured for the subnet to be public. Where you have `Target ****************`, is this the Internet Gateway (something like `igw-ab7ff6b1`)? If it's not an Internet Gateway, then you won't be able to RDP to those instances. Create an Internet Gateway, attach it to the VPC and then create a rule in the route table for Destination `0.0.0.0/0` to the Internet Gateway.

Once you have an Internet Gateway, you'll need to also ensure that your Network ACLs are allowing RDP access in and out of the subnet.

Comment: Apart from above points, if you trying to connect from inside the company network, then check with system admin that there are no blocking firewalls.